# Lifetime Probability and data loss

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have an HDD and I know that the probability of failure of the HDD on any given day is p. I know that the expected lifetime of the HDD should be 1/p. What if I buy another HDD and copy everything inside? How can I find the expected time when I will lose some data (i.e. when both HDD break considering i'm not changing the first that fails)? 
I know that both have an expected lifetime of 1/p. Does it mean that they should break the same day or that I have less probability that both will break in the expected time that is 1/p?

Comment: Sounds like you’re asking for the expected time until both fail, which would be the sum of the two failure times. If they’re both IID geometric RVs then the sum is negative-binomially distributed.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point, why should be the sum of the two failure times? The time should be when the second event happens. And since they both have the same life expectancy why should it matter if I have 2 of them?

Comment: If you have two components both with identically and independently distributed lifetimes then the time to failure of the first, is the minimum of the two RVs and the time to failure of second is the maximum of the two. The time until both fail is the sum because you wait for one to fail and then the other, irrelevant of which failed first or second. It was not clear to me which you wanted from the question. Sounds like you want the maximum of two Geometric RVs now...

Comment: I'll try to reformulate the question. I have the HDD A and B. Both have p probability to fail every day. So the expected lifetime (EL) of a singular HDD is 1/p. So, for example if p =0.5 EL = 2 days. Knowing that, I want to know what happens if these two HDD are copies of each other. In order to lose data both HDD need to fail  You're saying that the EL of the system composed by the two different HHD is 1/p+1/p. At this point I'd like to know howto calculate the "window" between the first event occur (that does not affect our system) and the second event occur that would mean the loss of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading over the comments it seems you have two components working in parallel (trying to keep the mathematical description of the problem general, so I use "components" instead of HDD, sorry). This means if one component fails the system still functions until the last component fails. So, the lifetime of the entire system depends on the lifetime of the last functioning component. If they all start in parallel at the same time, then it is the maximum lifetime time of the components we are concerned with finding the expectation (contrast with a series system where the failure of any one component shuts down the entire system so the failure time of the system is the minimum of all the component lifetimes).

Assume the component lifetimes are IID geometric RVs, $W_1, W_2$ with parameter $p$ taking values in $\mathbb{N}$, so that $\mathbb{E}(W_1)=1/p=\mathbb{E}(W_2)$. Assuming they are in use from the same starting time, and the system works until both components fail, then the entire system fails after $W=\max\{W_1, W_2\}$ time.

Note that $\{W\leq k\}=\{W_1 \leq k\} \cap \{W_2 \leq k\}$ so since these are IID, $\mathbb{P}(W\leq k)=\mathbb{P}(W_1 \leq k)^2$ follows. The CDF of a geometric RV with specified parameterization is $\mathbb{P}(W_1 \leq k)=1-q^k$ for $k=1,2,\dotsc$, where $q=1-p$.

Then, the expected time until the entire system fails is 
$$\mathbb{E}(W)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(W>k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1-\mathbb{P}(W\leq k)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1-\mathbb{P}(W_1\leq k)^2$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1-(1-q^k)^2$$
$$=\frac{q(q+2)}{(1-q)(1+q)}$$
$$=\frac{(1-p)(3-p)}{p(2-p)},$$
which then yields $E(W)\approx 1.667$ for $p=0.5$.

Comment: rereading my whole problem maybe I just stupidly assumed that the 2 components worked in parallel and not in series that would have made much more sense. Anyway, thank you for the exhaustive explanation. For the series is indeed the sum of the 2 components expected lifetime since I can "plug in my second HDD after the failure of the first one"

Comment: Something is wrong. Obviously the expected time to both failing should be at least the expected time until a single component failing. Since the latter is already 2 for $p = 0.5$, the former can not be 1.667.

Comment: Ok, I think I identified where the error is. Instead of $\mathbb{E}(W) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(W > k)$ we have  $\mathbb{E}(W) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(W \mathbf{\geq} k)$. Do you agree?

Comment: This could equivalently be stated as starting the summation at 0 rather than 1, which then, following your computation would yield $E(W) = 8/3 \approx 2.667$ for $p = 1/2$.

Comment: @Vincent Good catch. I’ll edit accordingly when I get the chance. Thanks.